# Angular Localization Issue with EJ2 Syncfusion

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, syncfusion, angular-i18n

I m working on the **Syncfusion Spreadsheet** component to play data like an excel. I implemented all necessary things with Syncfusion documents. But I have an issue in there. I m trying to format numbers as **"1.000,50"** for my localization. The default format is **"1,000.50"**. I couldnt solve the problem. Any suggestions to help ? Can I manipulate any file include the default number format for that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of standard formatting.

This may help you:

```
a = 1000.50; // your value
a.toLocaleString() // 1,000.5
a.toLocaleString('de') // 1.000,5
a.toLocaleString('de', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}) // 1.000,50
```

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your reported issue and the localization applied properly for other cultures in our latest version. We suspect that you haven’t properly refer the cldr-data package files in your application.

For more details, regarding the globalization. Please refer the below link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12566/how-to-globalize-the-currency-date-and-time-formats-applied-data-in-javascript-spreadsheet

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/common/internationalization/

Could you please check the above link and ensure whether you have properly referred the cldr-data package files in your application.